# is it bad practice to use recursion in a constructor?

Tags: java, recursion, van-emde-boas-trees

I'm implementing van Emde Boas trees and I've come across a situation where using recursion in the constructor is incredibly useful.

When I create the root node in the tree, that node will have pointers to many other nodes, and those nodes will point to many other nodes, and so on.  Even if these are intialized with null data, I still want them all there.

EDIT: In answer to a comment, I thought it might be bad practice because we always need to be careful when allocating memory.  In this case the user may not be aware of the effects allocating a new such node may have, and so they might allocate more memory then they intended?  Other then that I think it just seemed odd/dangerous to allocate memory in a constructor.

The code recursively creates new nodes until the full tree has been created.  Is this a bad practice? If so is there a better way to do it in Java?

```
//Constructor
public VEBNode(int universeSize)
{
    this.universeSize = universeSize;
    min = vEBTree.NULL;
    max = vEBTree.NULL;

    if(universeSize <= 2)
    {
        summary = null;
        cluster = null;
    }
    else
    {
        int childUnivereSize = (int)Math.sqrt(universeSize);

        summary = new VEBNode(childUnivereSize);
        cluster = new VEBNode[childUnivereSize];

        for(int i = 0; i < childUnivereSize; i++)
        {
            cluster[i] = new VEBNode(childUnivereSize);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it might it be a bad practice?

Comment: In your position, I might keep the constructor very basic and move all this logic to a static factory method, but that's a stylistic judgement call.

Comment: I think that recursion is quite a proper way to go in your situation, be it constructor or some other function.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer that reflects on possible dangers of this? I can't see any obvious problem with this, as long as it's really aggregation what you want.

Comment: @Eelke - You did notice this is a *Java* question, don't you? There are no destructors and no memory-deallocation in Java, thus no problem.

Answer (score 3):

You typically violate the "D" of SOLID principles:

**Dependency inversion principle**

> The principle states:
>
> A. High-level modules should not depend on
> low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions. B. Abstractions
> should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon
> abstractions.

Indeed, your constructor instantiates a concrete class: itself => no enough flexible and hard to test. (recursion of mocks? :))

Answer (score 2):

I can't think on a case for which this can be considered bad practice.

Constructors are meant to fully build an instance of a class, so if recursion is needed, it's not wrong to use it.

However, just for clarity, you may want to keep a simple constructor and implement the recursion in another (private) method... but that's up to you. Of course, if you put the recursion in another method, you can call it from your constructor. The result is the same, but the code may look cleaner and clearer.

Comment: I agree that moving the logic to an init method or a factory method would be preferable. Good suggestion.

Comment: Make sure you do not pass any references to `this` around from the constructor however...

Answer (score 1):

In general, doing resource-intensive stuff in constructor might be advised-against.

How about separating "constructor" from "building the whole tree" ?

Also, do You plan to have subclasses?

Comment: I don't plan to subclass this.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is a place where you give birth to your object. It should be simple and straight forward.

If you need to initialize your object with some values - externalize the calculation of those values.

As I understand calling methods from a constructor is a bad practice. I'd use a delegate class, that encapsulate all the logic.

Put all complicated logic in a separate service class (but again - not in constructor) and use - delegate all calculations to that service class.

Constructor is just too sensitive place to hold complicated (which includes recursive) logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to subclass this class - then the recursion will make quite a lot of pain for you, because you will not be able to override this constructor so that you created instances of a subclass.